# How to remove brackets from JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have this JSON data:

```
var tmpStr = '[    
{
    "Name": "TEST",
    "deviceId": "",
    "CartId": "",
    "timestamp": 1383197265540,
    "FOOD": [],
    "City": "LONDON CA"
 }

]';
```

How can I delete the brackets?

Here is more of my JSON file:

```
[{"arrivee":false,"des":"Ceintures De Sécurité Conducteur","code":"nn","depart":true},
 {"arrivee":true,"des"‌​‌​:"Lecteur Tachygraphe","code":"nn","depart":false}
 {"arrivee":false,"d‌​‌​es":"Ceintures De Sécurités Passagères","code":"nn","depart":true},
 {"arrivee":true,"des"‌​‌​:"Climatisation","‌​co‌​de":"nn","depart‌​":fa‌​lse}]
```

Answer (score 3):

[Parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) the [JSON](http://json.org/) string and use the first element of the array.

```js
var tmpStr = '[{"Name": "TEST","deviceId": "", "CartId": "", "timestamp": 383197265540, "FOOD": [], "City": "LONDON CA" }]',
    object = JSON.parse(tmpStr)[0];

console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thank u for ur answer but it gives me an error:Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: please add the string without any format to the question. where do you get the string from?

Comment: actually I have a lot of objects not only one

Comment: to find the error, you may add some object to the question, just to enable an answer.

Comment: here is actually my real json file: [{"arrivee":false,"des":"Ceintures De Sécurité Conducteur","code":"nn","depart":true},{"arrivee":true,"des":"Lecteur Tachygraphe","code":"nn","depart":false},{"arrivee":false,"des":"Ceintures De Sécurités Passagères","code":"nn","depart":true},{"arrivee":true,"des":"Climatisation","code":"nn","depart":false}]

Comment: any help please!!

Comment: @estemestem Seriously, learn to ask a proper question please! As for your  comment question, I think you don't have a JSON object but a JSON **string**. Use `JSON.parse()` to parse it as JSON and then use the answer provided.

Comment: exactly i have a json abject...I'm sorry it was a mistake...but how i resolve this problem

Comment: either you have an object or a json string, there is no json object.

Comment: @estemestem The other comments are right - JSON is the *representation of* an object, not the object itself. Just ask yourself if you'd rather eat a cake or its recipe. Also, it would be good to include this JSON in the question itself (rather than in comments) if it's a substantial part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

You dont have to delete brackes, just do this,

```
var result = tmpStr[0];
```

Comment: thank u for ur answer but it gives me an error:Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: @estemestem then your JSON is different than what you posted.  because the JSON you posted is properly formed.

Comment: here is actually my real json file: [{"arrivee":false,"des":"Ceintures De Sécurité Conducteur","code":"nn","depart":true},{"arrivee":true,"des"‌​:"Lecteur Tachygraphe","code":"nn","depart":false},{"arrivee":false,"d‌​es":"Ceintures De Sécurités Passagères","code":"nn","depart":true},{"arrivee":true,"des"‌​:"Climatisation","co‌​de":"nn","depart":fa‌​lse}]

Comment: any help please!!

Comment: why?? just i4m trying to get data from backend, and what i got is the file above, but i want to remove the brackets, help please!!

Answer (score 2):

**Description:**
You wouldn't want to, this is a JSON array of Objects

```
[ // this starts an array
    { // this starts an object
        "Name": "TEST", // this is a property named 'Name'
        "deviceId": "", // this is a property named 'deviceId'
        "CartId": "", // this is a property named 'CartId'
        "timestamp": 1383197265540, // this is a property named 'timestamp'
        "FOOD": [], // this is a property named 'FOOD'
        "City": "LONDON CA" // this is a property named 'City'
    } // this ends an object
] // this ends an array
```

Comment: here is actually my real json file: [{"arrivee":false,"des":"Ceintures De Sécurité Conducteur","code":"nn","depart":true},{"arrivee":true,"des"‌​:"Lecteur Tachygraphe","code":"nn","depart":false},{"arrivee":false,"d‌​es":"Ceintures De Sécurités Passagères","code":"nn","depart":true},{"arrivee":true,"des"‌​:"Climatisation","co‌​de":"nn","depart":fa‌​lse}]

Comment: @estemestem you are getting invalid JSON, this is because of the string containing symbol characters (IE it is in french)

Comment: The fact that it is in French is not the problem (A string value can be any valid Unicode character except some escape characters). The problem is that your JSON (as posted) is not valid, as it contains a number of invalid (hidden) characters. Run your JSON through a linter like [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) and it will show them to you.